# Device Tree Overlays and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, beagleboneblack, beagleboard, device-tree

I recently downloaded and began using an [Ubuntu 16.04 image built by Robert Nelson](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu#eMMC:_BeagleBone_Black) for the Beagle Bone Black on a microSD card.  All is well and the BBB is up and running.  But, it appears the cap manager is no longer being used.  I am relatively new to the BBB and the device tree, so my question is this - in this kernel, is the BBB still using device tree overlays or are we supposed to deal directly with the dts file as it looks like Robert's [Really Simple Cape Manager](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/rscm) does?  If this is the case, does this mean that we have to create a patch for every cape that we wish to use?

Comment: Did you find out if BBB is using device tree overlays?

Comment: So, I am stretching back a bit because I had to put this on the back burner, but I believe the answer is yes.  It is using DTOs and is no different from the other versions (located in the same directory and everything).  The issue is that you can not load them on the fly like you can with previous versions.  So, if you have a cape that loads a DTO at boot, it will do this for you, no problem.